# ORA-00904 with UNION and ORDER BY alias

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run the following query using Oracle's sample HR schema, I get an "invalid identifer" error:

```
SELECT 'countries' AS table_name, COUNT(*) AS num_records
FROM countries
UNION
SELECT 'departments', COUNT(*)
FROM departments
UNION
SELECT 'employees', COUNT(*)
FROM employees
UNION
SELECT 'job_history', COUNT(*)
FROM job_history
UNION
SELECT 'jobs', COUNT(*)
FROM jobs
UNION
SELECT 'locations', COUNT(*)
FROM locations
UNION
SELECT 'regions', COUNT(*)
FROM regions
ORDER BY num_records;
```

The specific error is:

```
ORA-00904: "NUM_RECORDS": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 21 Column: 10
```

The error goes away if I re-add the alias to one of the other query parts, but only one:

```
SELECT 'countries' AS table_name, COUNT(*) AS num_records
FROM countries
UNION
SELECT 'departments', COUNT(*)
FROM departments
UNION
SELECT 'employees', COUNT(*)
FROM employees
UNION
SELECT 'job_history', COUNT(*)
FROM job_history
UNION
SELECT 'jobs', COUNT(*)
FROM jobs
UNION
SELECT 'locations', COUNT(*) AS num_records
FROM locations
UNION
SELECT 'regions', COUNT(*)
FROM regions
ORDER BY num_records;
```

Notice that I have added `AS num_records` after `COUNT(*)` on the SELECT from locations. When I do this, the query runs as expected and I get results like:

```
TABLE_NAME  NUM_RECORDS
----------- -----------
regions               4
job_history          11
jobs                 19
locations            23
countries            25
departments          27
employees           108

7 rows selected.
```

Adding the alias to any other one of the query parts does not make the error go away. This feels very strange to me. Anyone know what's going on?

For what it's worth, it's not just with this schema. I found the same issue with another schema as well.

Comment: Does it work if you do `ORDER BY 2`?

Comment: this is a know bug

Comment: I tried it myself in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40f84/13/1, its still a known bug and oracle don't have solution until now.

Comment: Thanks, all. @GMB, yes `ORDER BY 2` works.